# Hibernate does not generate correct h2 ddl when default values of char columns involved

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, unit-testing, h2

I wanted to test some Spring boot CRUDrepository queries

`mvn dependency:tree` output

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.6.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.6.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.6.5.Final:compile <== I tried overloading it in pom also
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.200:test
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:2.1.210:test <== also tried 2.1.210
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource: 
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:TGPLLIB;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS MYSCHEMA
    username: sa
    password: sa
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
```

I use @SpringBootTest to initialize context, however I found that for entities that have columns with default value, the SQL created seems strange.

I am receiving errors that the ddl to create table is incorrect

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement 
"CREATE TABLE MYSCHEMA.TBL1 (COL1 VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
COL2 VARCHAR(1024) DEFAULT ,[*] COL3 INTEGER DEFAULT 0, 
COL4 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, COL5 VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL";
expected "NOT, EXISTS, INTERSECTS, UNIQUE";
SQL statement:
create table MYSCHEMA.TBL1 (COL1 varchar(20) not null,
COL2 varchar(1024) default , COL3 integer default 0, 
COL4 varchar(10) not null, COL5 varchar(3) not null, 
primary key (COL1 )) [42001-200]
```

It seems to me it cannot create `default ''` or `default 'value'`

I noticed every column that has the pattern `@ColumnDefault(value = "anything double quoted")` has this problem, e.g. for below, column nam1 have no issue while column nam2 will have the issue, in the above example it even showed `[*]` to where it think the syntax was wrong

```
@Column(name = "NAM1")
@ColumnDefault(value = "0")
private int nam1;

@Column(name = "NAM2", length = 1024)
@ColumnDefault(value = "")
private String nam2;
```

I tested "" empty string, "anystring" in ColumnDefault value, both gives error, for "anystring" it generates ddl `"default anystring"` instead of `"default 'anystring'"`.

I also checked another project with same pom setup but (luckily) no default values in entity, it does not have this issue while testing with H2.

So I am unsure, if I am missing anything specific about the connection string, the dialect setting,

I tried `;MODE=LEGACY` `;NON_KEYWORD=VALUE`, they were not supported

also `spring.jpa.database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect`

or is this just a hibernate h2 issue, and if there is any workaround for it.

Comment: It is the dialect that generates the sql. The JDBC url (unless you haven't specified a dialect) doesn't matter, I also doubt an empty string is a valid default value. It should, according to the documentation (which I suggest to read), it should return a SQL expression `anystring` isn't a SQL expression `'anystring'` is. So use `@ColumnDefault("''")` if you want an empty string.

Comment: good point, seems some other online code sample are also like that, may be I misunderstood this concept, let me try

Comment: @M.Deinum another very strange thing I just noticed, not all columns with `@ColumnDefault(value = "")` suffered this. But thanks for your help nonetheless as now all passes. On the other hand I am still unable to find the document reference to such scenario, just some code examples here and there, you mind sharing with me what documentation you found or keywords you search for? I just want to make sure this also works for production database which is DB2

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html this here contained 1 code sample which aligns with what you said, I think that will do for me.